# How to cleanly kill Ubuntu onboard keyboard with keystroke from the onboard keyboard

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, keyboard, kill

I am trying to close the Ubuntu onscreen keyboard named onboard with a command entered by that keyboard.  What happens is if I type a kill command such as the following using the onscreen keyboard itself. . .

```
 killall onboard
```

and then hit Enter again on the onscreen keyboard, I get continuous Enter hits on the terminal I was on.  It's like I unplugged a physical keyboard and it keeps thinking I'm hitting the key I depressed as it was being unplugged.

I can't find any documentation online for how to do this any better so I thought I would ask here.  I've tried the following sending the following kill signals which all have the same behavior:  1 (SIGHUP), 2 (SIGINT), 9 (SIGKILL), 15 (SIGTERM), and 24 (SIGXCPU).

Any ideas?  I'm hoping I'm missing something obvious. . .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So I found the answer:  https://bugs.launchpad.net/onboard/+bug/1032042

Once you have onboard 0.99 installed and running, you can execute the following two commands to show and hide the keyboard respectively without having to kill the process:

```
dbus-send --type=method_call --dest=org.onboard.Onboard /org/onboard/Onboard/Keyboard org.onboard.Onboard.Keyboard.Show

dbus-send --type=method_call --dest=org.onboard.Onboard /org/onboard/Onboard/Keyboard org.onboard.Onboard.Keyboard.Hide
```

This solved all my problems in a way better than just killing it.

Comment: This worked well in lubuntu with along with obkey for a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I found also a toggle command:

`dbus-send --type=method_call --dest=org.onboard.Onboard /org/onboard/Onboard/Keyboard org.onboard.Onboard.Keyboard.ToggleVisible`